# ActiveMQ Artemis / Influx Telegraf MQTT Listener - all messages (100K) delivered, but 4K messages remain in queue

Tags: mqtt, influxdb, activemq-artemis, telegraf

I have conducted a test sending 100K persistent MQTT messages (QoS 2) to ActiveMQ Artemis. The topic has two Telegraf listeners, one on VM 85 and the other on VM 86. These listeners write data to the InfluxDB on their respective servers.

The main goal of the test is to ensure all messages delivered to VM 85 are also delivered to VM 86 even if VM 86 is down. Before executing the test both listeners connect to the broker each with a unique client ID and with clean-session = false and subscribe to the topic using QoS 2. This ensures the subscription for each is present when the messages are sent whether or not the listeners are actually active. Neither listener is connected when the test starts. The order of operations is:

1. Start listener on VM 85.
2. Send data.
3. Ensure messages are delivered to listener on VM 85.
4. Start listener on VM 86.
5. Ensure messages are delivered to listener on VM 86.

The good news is that all messages are delivered to the Influx DB on both VMs. However, the relevant queue for VM 86 still shows about 4.3 K messages remaining, as shown below:

[image]

If I then restart the listener on VM 86, it shows it's writing more data, as shown below:

[image: restart of Telegraf listener on 86 shows writes]

However, the total messages in the InfluxDB correctly remains at 100K. If InfluxDB receives a duplicate record, it will overwrite it. However, the client is incrementing by one and setting the date at each increment, so this shouldn't occur, at least from the client.

I'm not clear on why this would be. Why does the the listener on VM 86 need to be restarted to completely empty the queue?

There is one parameter I haven't tried in the [Telegraf plugin](https://www.influxdata.com/integration/mqtt-telegraf-consumer/):

```
## Maximum messages to read from the broker that have not been written by an
## output.  For best throughput set based on the number of metrics within
## each message and the size of the output's metric_batch_size.
##
## For example, if each message from the queue contains 10 metrics and the
## output metric_batch_size is 1000, setting this to 100 will ensure that a
## full batch is collected and the write is triggered immediately without
## waiting until the next flush_interval.
# max_undelivered_messages = 1000
```

It seems the batch size defaults to `1000`, based on the output messages. But the maximum messages to read before output seems to be something greater, since 4.3K are output when restarted. Except that they have already been output. That's the confusing part.

Client Code:

```
package abc;

import java.time.Instant;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttSecurityException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence;

import com.influxdb.client.domain.WritePrecision;
import com.influxdb.client.write.Point;

public class MqttPublishSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MqttSecurityException, MqttException, InterruptedException {

        String broker = "tcp://localhost:1883";
        String clientId = "JavaSample";
        MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();

        int qos = 2; 
        
        int start = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        int end = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        String topic = args[2];

        if (topic == null) {
            topic = "testtopic/999";
        }
        
                
        System.out.println("start: " + start + ", end: " + end + ", topic: " + topic + " qos: " + qos);

        MqttClient sampleClient = new MqttClient(broker, clientId, persistence);
        MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
        connOpts.setCleanSession(false);
        connOpts.setUserName("admin");

        connOpts.setPassword("xxxxxxx".toCharArray());
        System.out.println("Connecting to broker: " + broker);
        sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
        System.out.println("Connected");

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            
            // print out every 1000
            
            if (i%100 == 0) {
                System.out.println("i: " + i);
            }
            
            try {

                Point point = Point.measurement("temperature").addTag("machine", "unit43").addField("external", i)
                        .time(Instant.now(), WritePrecision.NS);

                content = point.toLineProtocol();

                MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(content.getBytes());
                message.setQos(qos);

                sampleClient.publish(topic, message);
                Thread.sleep(10);

            } catch (MqttException me) {
                System.out.println("reason " + me.getReasonCode());
                System.out.println("msg " + me.getMessage());
                System.out.println("loc " + me.getLocalizedMessage());
                System.out.println("cause " + me.getCause());
                System.out.println("excep " + me);
                me.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        sampleClient.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Disconnected");

    }

}
```

Telegraph Plugin on 85:

```
###############################################################################
#                             INPUT PLUGINS                                   #
###############################################################################

  
[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  servers = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:1883"]

  ## Topics that will be subscribed to.
  topics = [
    "testtopic/#",
  ]

  ## The message topic will be stored in a tag specified by this value.  If set
  ## to the empty string no topic tag will be created.
  # topic_tag = "topic"

  ## When using a QoS of 1 or 2, you should enable persistent_session to allow
  ## resuming unacknowledged messages.
  qos = 2


  persistent_session = true

  ## If unset, a random client ID will be generated.
  client_id = "InfluxData_on_86_listen_local"

  ## Username and password to connect MQTT server.
  username = "admin"
  password = "xxxxxx"

  data_format = "influx"

[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  servers = ["tcp://10.102.11.86:1883"]

  ## Topics that will be subscribed to.
  topics = [
    "testtopic/#",
  ]

  ## The message topic will be stored in a tag specified by this value.  If set
  ## to the empty string no topic tag will be created.
  # topic_tag = "topic"

  ## When using a QoS of 1 or 2, you should enable persistent_session to allow
  ## resuming unacknowledged messages.
  qos = 2


  persistent_session = true

  ## If unset, a random client ID will be generated.
  client_id = "InfluxData_on_86_listen_85"

  ## Username and password to connect MQTT server.
  username = "admin"
  password = "xxxx"

  data_format = "influx"


###############################################################################
#                            OUTPUT PLUGINS                                   #
###############################################################################


[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  ## The URLs of the InfluxDB cluster nodes.
  ##
  ## Multiple URLs can be specified for a single cluster, only ONE of the
  ## urls will be written to each interval.
  urls = ["http://127.0.0.1:8086"]
  
  ## Token for authentication.
  token = "xxxx"
  
  ## Organization is the name of the organization you wish to write to.
  organization = "xxxx"

  # ## Destination bucket to write into.
  bucket = "events"
```

Comment: You don't need to include text describing the edits you made. You just need to ensure the question makes sense as a whole. If folks are curious about the edits you've made they can look through all of them via the link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Does that help? You will have to scroll to the right to see the actual number.

Comment: The goal is to ensure all messages delivered to server 85 are delivered to server 86 when server 86 is down. So the order of operations is 1. Start listener on 85 only. 2. Send data to 85. 3. Start listener on 86. 4. Ensure messages are delivered to 86.

Comment: The listeners are configured with QOS=2,   persistent_session = true (clean-session=false),  separate client id for each listener, not sure about the MQTT version, but it seems to support MQTT 3 semantics (I will check on this).

Comment: If InfluxDB receives a duplicate record, it will overwrite it. However, the client is incrementing by one and setting the date at each increment, so this shouldn't occur, at least from the client.

Comment: Yes. I was doing it all morning with the same client ids.

Comment: There is one parameter I haven't tried in the telegraf plugin:


  ## Maximum messages to read from the broker that have not been written by an
  ## output.  For best throughput set based on the number of metrics within
  ## each message and the size of the output's metric_batch_size.
 
  ## e.g if each message from the queue contains 10 metrics and the
  ## output metric_batch_size is 1000, setting this to 100 will ensure that a
  ## full batch is collected and the write is triggered immediately without
  ## waiting until the next flush_interval.
  # max_undelivered_messages = 1000

Comment: It seems the batch size defaults to 1000, based on the output messages. But the maximum messages to read before output seems to be something greater, since 4.3K are  output when restarted. Except that they have already been output. That's the confusing part.

Comment: It's really important to keep clarifying your question as details are requested via comments. You don't want folks to have to scroll through a bunch of comments in order to understand your question. Once the requested details are added to the question then those comments are free to be deleted. This is one key factor that separates Stack Overflow from traditional discussion forums. The goal is to have really clear questions and answers with as little discussion as possible (ideally none). To that end, I've taken your feedback in the comments and added it to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: What exactly is the client "incrementing by one" and when you say "the client" do you mean the MQTT listener which is inserting records into the InfluxDB?

Comment: Right, the client has a value "external" which is incremented by 1. I will post the code.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to replicate this issue even initially at lower volumes, although I had it twice at 100K messages.

When i added the following parameters to the Telegraf Listener:

```
  max_undelivered_messages = 100
```

It seemed to slow things down, as batches were limited to 100 according to the telegraph output.

However, when I removed it, it seemed batches where still limited to 100.

Finally, I changed the same parameter to 1000:

```
  max_undelivered_messages = 1000
```

After this, message batch sizes improved to well beyond 100, as they were initially.

Furthermore, at least on the third try of 100K messages, there are no longer any messages remaining in the queue after the sequence described in the question is completed.

I'm not really sure if this change did anything, but in any case the correct amount of messages were always being received.

So, I'm marking this as answered.